# How avoid seams between ARframes capturedImages

Tags: arkit, image-stitching

I gather images from different ARframes of my ARKit session.
When I combine different images (= Image stitching) for example of a single blue wall, some images are light blue, other dark blue etc...
As a consequence there are visible seams between pictures.
How can I avoid those seams ?

I tried to lock the camera configuration but it didn't help :

````
 let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
        do {
            try device?.lockForConfiguration()
            device?.exposureMode = .locked
            device?.focusMode = .locked
            device?.whiteBalanceMode = .locked
        } catch {
            // handle error
            NSLog("lockForConfiguration error : %@",error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }```
````